# why using matplotlib text alignent with string format functions works wrong?

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, plot, text-alignment

I am trying to align my texts to right in matplotlib bars. The following codes works just fine:

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
for color in colors:
    print('{:>15}'.format(color))
```

output:

```
        red
       blue
      green
     yellow
```

However, the same string format doesn't work in plt.text functions:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar_band = ax.barh(range(len(colors)), np.ones(len(colors)), height=1)
for i in range(len(colors)):
    bar_band[i].set_color(colors[i])
    ax.text(0.1, i+0.4, "{:>15}".format(colors[i]))

ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

I got texts aligns to center instead. Can any one help me on this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mki3f.png)

Comment: as you can find in the docstring of ax.text(), there are optional parameters called `horizontalalignment` and `verticalalignment` that might do the job

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/alignment_test.html

Answer (score 0):

[`ax.text()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text) creates a matplotlib `Text` object, which have the option [`horizontalalignment`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_horizontalalignment) (or `ha` for short). This can help you to align the text to your desired position.

Accepted options are `'left'`, `'right'` and `'center'`

So, you might try:

```
ax.text(0.1, i+0.4, "{:>15}".format(colors[i]), ha='right')
```